# Upload nested directories to S3 with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have been trying to upload a static website to s3 with the following cli command:

`aws s3 sync . s3://my-website-bucket --acl public-read`

It successfully uploads every file in the root directory but fails on the nested directories with the following:

`An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the ListObjects operation: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256`

I have found references to this issue on GitHub but no clear instruction of how to solve it.

Comment: Can you paste your command for the nested directories? Also are those sub directories empty or they have files in them?

Comment: The nested directories have files in them, yes. I assumed that the above command would encompass all sub directories...

Comment: Interesting, the s3 sync command should recursively copy the local folders to folder like s3 objects. Can you check the following thread and confirm whether you are setting the region correctly? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235135. The same has been reported by another user on thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203011/invalidrequest-s3-ls

Comment: @Shibashis This was the correct answer, I had an incorrect region configured. If you want to add this as an answer Id be happy to up vote and tick it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s3 sync command recursively copies the local folders to folder like s3 objects.

Even though S3 doesn't really support folders, the sync command creates the s3 objects with a format which will have the folder names in their keys.

As reported on the following amazon support thread "forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235135" the issue should be solved by setting the region correctly.

Answer (score 0):

S3 has no concept of directories.
S3 is an object store where each object is identified by a key.
The key might be a string like "dir1/dir2/dir3/test.txt"

AWS graphical user interfaces on top of S3 interpret the "/" characters as a directory separator and present the file list "as is" it was in a directory structure.

However, internally, there is no concept of directory, S3 has a flat namespace.
See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html for more details.

This is the reason directories are not synced as there is no directories on S3.

Also the feature request is open in https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/912 but has not been added yet.

Comment: The region was my issue here. `aws configure` didn't verify my region input and no error message flagged the invalid region so it was all a bit cryptic.

Comment: Yes S3 doesn't actually support directories. However that has nothing to do with the question being asked. The S3 sync command does absolutely support syncing directories to S3. Your statement that the command didn't sync directories because S3 doesn't support directories is not correct. The S3 sync command supports syncing directories, just not **empty** directories. I'm not sure why this is marked as the answer, because it is incorrect.